# "The function/feature is not implemented" error when running opencv example

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I get the error below when running the following code:

```
import cv2, sys, numpy, os 
haar_file = 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
datasets = 'datasets'
print('Recognizing Face Please Be in sufficient Lights...') 
(images, lables, names, id) = ([], [], {}, 0) 
for (subdirs, dirs, files) in os.walk(datasets): 
    for subdir in dirs: 
        names[id] = subdir 
        subjectpath = os.path.join(datasets, subdir) 
        for filename in os.listdir(subjectpath): 
            path = subjectpath + '/' + filename 
            lable = id
            images.append(cv2.imread(path)) 
            lables.append(int(lable)) 
        id += 1
(width, height) = (130, 100) 
(images, lables) = [numpy.array(lis) for lis in [images, lables]] 
model = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create() 

model.train(images, lables) # error comes here

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(haar_file) 
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
while True: 
    (_, im) = webcam.read() 
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5) 
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces: 
        cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2) 
        face = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w] 
        face_resize = cv2.resize(face, (width, height)) 
        prediction = model.predict(face_resize) 
        cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3) 
        if prediction[1]<500: 
             cv2.putText(im, '% s' % 
                         (names[prediction[0]]), (x-10, y-10),  
                         cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, (0, 255, 0)) 
        else: 
            cv2.putText(im, 'not recognized',  
                        (x-10, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, (0, 255, 0)) 
            cv2.imshow('OpenCV', im) 
            key = cv2.waitKey(10) 
            if key == 27: 
                break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

the error that pops up is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Y:\vigyantram\AI-20200807T104521Z-001\AI\img processing1\face_recognize.py", line 19, in <module>
    model.train(images, lables)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.3.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv_contrib\modules\face\src\lbph_faces.cpp:265: error: (-213:The function/feature is not implemented) Using Original Local Binary Patterns for feature extraction only works on single-channel images (given 16). Please pass the image data as a grayscale image! in function 'cv::face::elbp'?
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not an OpenCV expert. I would only suggest you put a little more love to your question.

Explain what the code should do, so it can also help other people. Also format the traceback properly. I'm sure people will gladly help you.

Comment: ok. I will try to do so

Comment: The error message says "Please pass the image data as a grayscale image!", which is most probably what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

This may solve the problem. Use size(width and height) multiple of 8 or 16 if it doesn't work let me know u need to convert both test and train images to grey try that also it will work.

```
import cv2, sys, numpy, os 
    haar_file = 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
    datasets = 'datasets'
    print('Recognizing Face Please Be in sufficient Lights...') 
    (images, lables, names, id) = ([], [], {}, 0) 
    for (subdirs, dirs, files) in os.walk(datasets): 
        for subdir in dirs: 
            names[id] = subdir 
            subjectpath = os.path.join(datasets, subdir) 
            for filename in os.listdir(subjectpath): 
                path = subjectpath + '/' + filename 
                lable = id
                images.append(cv2.imread(path)) 
                lables.append(int(lable)) 
            id += 1

    (width, height) = (200, 200) #here 200 is multiple of 8
    (images, lables) = [numpy.array(lis) for lis in [images, lables]] 
    model = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create() 
    model.train(images, lables) #error comes here
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(haar_file) 
    webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
    while True: 
        (_, im) = webcam.read() 
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5) 
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces: 
            cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2) 
            face = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w] 
            face_resize = cv2.resize(face, (width, height)) 
            prediction = model.predict(face_resize) 
            cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 3) 
            if prediction[1]<500: 
               cv2.putText(im, '% s' % 
    (names[prediction[0]]), (x-10, y-10),  
    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, (0, 255, 0)) 
            else: 
              cv2.putText(im, 'not recognized',  
    (x-10, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1, (0, 255, 0)) 
        cv2.imshow('OpenCV', im) 
        key = cv2.waitKey(10) 
        if key == 27: 
            break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

i got to know what to do.

```
images.append(cv2.imread(path,0))
```

The '0' had to be added.